# Error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'npy_intp' to 'int'

Tags: python, theano, pymc3, hierarchical-bayesian, probabilistic-programming

I am trying to run the following model, but it fails during compilation:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm


def sample_data(G=1, K=2):
    # mean proportion ([0,1]) for each g
    p_g = np.random.beta(2, 2, size=G)

    # concentration around each p_g
    c_g = np.random.lognormal(mean=0.5, sigma=1, size=G)

    # reparameterization for standard Beta(a,b)
    a_g = c_g * p_g / np.sqrt(p_g**2 + (1.-p_g)**2)
    b_g = c_g*(1.-p_g) / np.sqrt(p_g**2 + (1.-p_g)**2)

    # for each p_g, sample K proportions
    p_gk = np.random.beta(a_g[:, np.newaxis], b_g[:, np.newaxis], size=(G, K))

    return p_gk

# Data size
G = 3
K = 5

# obtain a G x K array of proportions p_gk in [0,1]
data = sample_data(G, K) 

with pm.Model() as m:

    # Parameters
    p_g = pm.Beta('p_g', 1., 1., shape=G)
    sd_g = pm.HalfNormal('sd_g', sd=1., shape=G)

    # Observed proportions
    p_gk = pm.Beta('p_gk', mu=p_g, sd=sd_g, shape=(G, K), observed=data)

    trace = pm.sample(2000)
```

with these errors:

```
Exception: ("Compilation failed (return status=1):

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:400:27: 
  error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'npy_intp' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].
     int init_totals[2] = {V3_n0, V3_n1};.
                           ^~~~~.

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:400:27:
  note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.
     int init_totals[2] = {V3_n0, V3_n1};.
                           ^~~~~.
                           static_cast<int>( ).

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:400:34: 
  error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'npy_intp' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].
     int init_totals[2] = {V3_n0, V3_n1};.
                                  ^~~~~.

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:400:34: 
  note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.
     int init_totals[2] = {V3_n0, V3_n1};.
                                  ^~~~~.
                                  static_cast<int>( ).

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:412:9: 
  error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].
         V3_stride0, V3_stride1, .
         ^~~~~~~~~~.

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:412:9: 
  note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.
         V3_stride0, V3_stride1, .
         ^~~~~~~~~~.
         static_cast<int>( ).

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:412:21: 
  error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].
         V3_stride0, V3_stride1, .
                     ^~~~~~~~~~.

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:412:21:
  note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.
         V3_stride0, V3_stride1, .
                     ^~~~~~~~~~.
                     static_cast<int>( ).

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:413:1: 
  error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].
 V1_stride0, V1_stride1.
 ^~~~~~~~~~.

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:413:1: 
  note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.
 V1_stride0, V1_stride1.
 ^~~~~~~~~~.
 static_cast<int>( ).

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:413:13:
  error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].
 V1_stride0, V1_stride1.
             ^~~~~~~~~~.

/Users/mfansler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.6.3-64/tmpr58gulp2/mod.cpp:413:13:
  note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.
 V1_stride0, V1_stride1.
             ^~~~~~~~~~.
             static_cast<int>( ).

6 errors generated.. ", '[Elemwise{log,no_inplace}(TensorConstant{[[0.297343..76841722]]})]')
```

I'm new to PyMC3. I don't see these errors when running existing PyMC3 examples. I suspect that I'm seeing these because I'm using a multidimensional format (i.e., `(G,K)`), since I haven't seen others using this format (I might be imposing my familiarity with Stan).

Generally, I'm having trouble getting a sense of how to implement multilevel models that have multiple dimensions.

Any idea what is causing the errors I'm seeing?

---

### Versions

- python 3.6.3
- numpy 1.14.5
- Theano 1.0.2
- pymc3 3.4.1
- Mac OS 10.13.5

---

## Update

I installed the same package versions (via `conda`) on an HPC node (CentOS 7), and was able to run [the modified version of the model suggested by @colcarroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51291640/570918).  However, on my OS X machine, I still see the Theano compilation errors indicated above, even with the model changes. Is this possibly a `clang` problem? Can one specify the compiler for Theano to use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One workaround is to suppress the compilation warnings:

```
import theano

theano.config.gcc.cxxflags = "-Wno-c++11-narrowing"
```

The extent to which these warnings matter for program correctness is unclear. They do not arise when I compile on CentOS 7 (even when explicitly checking for them with `-Wc++11-narrowing`). The sampling results on Mac OS X with suppressed errors and CentOS without were comparable.

I would still prefer to see an answer that explains the underlying issue.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me. It's still throwing the errors on OS X, even with this flag set and having run theano-cache purge.

Comment: @WesleyTansey what versions?

Comment: I'm on pymc3 3.8 and theano 1.0.5. I think I am running into a combination of known issues. First, I was importing seaborn (https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/3849). Second, I was importing everything inside a local function that was inside the if __name__ == '__main__' bit. These two issues ended up with the model compiling but then compiler errors thrown during multiprocessing for the NUTS samples.

Comment: Seems this is still a problem in ipython, though. i'll open a new issue.

Comment: @WesleyTansey be sure to report any Conda environment versions (if using that), including the channels where the packages are from.

Comment: I ended up not posting. Installing the latest dev version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - You do have to be a bit more explicit about shapes for higher dimensions. The library does a little to be "clever", but if you provide the `shape` argument, it will use that.

Your example here is *syntactically* fixed by setting

```
with pm.Model() as m:

    # Parameters
    p_g = pm.Beta('p_g', 1., 1., shape=(G, 1))
    sd_g = pm.HalfNormal('sd_g', sd=1, shape=(G, 1))

    # Observed proportions
    p_gk = pm.Beta('p_gk', mu=p_g.dot(np.ones((1,K))), sd=sd_g.dot(np.ones((1, K))), shape=(G, K), observed=data)
    trace = pm.sample()
```

Note that running `m.check_test_point()` wil show that `p_gk` has 0 probability. This is because `sd_g` is too wide, and PyMC3 tries to initialize that at 0.8, which is out of the support of a `mu, sd` parametrized beta distribution.

Setting `sd_g = pm.HalfNormal('sd_g', sd=0.1, shape=(G, 1))` allows you to also sample from the model, though this may not be the prior you intended!

Comment: This looks like the advice I was hoping to find, but it doesn't seem to make any difference w.r.t. the compilation error I am seeing.  Error comes out exactly the same.  If this works for you, could you perhaps share your environment info?

Comment: Tried this on an HPC node (CentOS 7), same versions of packages installed through `conda` and it worked fine.  Is this a Mac OS X / clang issue I'm seeing?  Are there ways to control the compiler that gets used by theano?

Comment: There was a big change in shape handling recently (https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/2983), so it might matter if you installed pymc3 v3.4.1 from master or not (I was on master).  I checked the above on OS X, and `theano.config.cxx` gives `clang++`.

Comment: I tried both latest release (via `conda`) and pulled master branch.  Both are fine on CentOS; both throw the compilation error on Mac OS X (and can be suppressed using the `-Wno-c++11-narrowing` flag).