# Compiling Error with pymc3 and theano while running bayesian hierarchical model

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, theano, pymc3, hierarchical-bayesian

I am running a bayesian hierarchical model on pymc3 and theano. When I start training my model I get this error:

```
 WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '16490' (I am process '7448')
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/subtensor.py:2197: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  rval = inputs[0].__getitem__(inputs[1:])
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/subtensor.py:2339: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  out[0][inputs[2:]] = inputs[1]

You can find the C code in this temporary file: /var/folders/dd/kb4xb1px7zxc5cwdk799b46c0000gn/T/theano_compilation_error_2qgug1um
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-67e4a92cfa79> in <module>
     29             mu=0, sd=1, shape=n_regs_in_net)
     30         mvg_regs = pm.MvNormal('MVG_%s_regs' % cur_netname,
---> 31             mu=mvg_mu, chol=chol, shape=n_regs_in_net)
     32
     33         # per region in the current network

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/distribution.py in __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs)
     45             total_size = kwargs.pop('total_size', None)
     46             dist = cls.dist(*args, **kwargs)
---> 47             return model.Var(name, dist, data, total_size)
     48         else:
     49             raise TypeError("Name needs to be a string but got: {}".format(name))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/model.py in Var(self, name, dist, data, total_size)
    920                 with self:
    921                     var = FreeRV(name=name, distribution=dist,
--> 922                                  total_size=total_size, model=self)
    923                 self.free_RVs.append(var)
    924             else:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/model.py in __init__(self, type, owner, index, name, distribution, total_size, model)
   1368             self.tag.test_value = np.ones(
   1369                 distribution.shape, distribution.dtype) * distribution.default()
-> 1370             self.logp_elemwiset = distribution.logp(self)
   1371             # The logp might need scaling in minibatches.
   1372             # This is done in `Factor`.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/multivariate.py in logp(self, value)
    313         TensorVariable
    314         """
--> 315         quaddist, logdet, ok = self._quaddist(value)
    316         k = value.shape[-1].astype(theano.config.floatX)
    317         norm = - 0.5 * k * pm.floatX(np.log(2 * np.pi))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/multivariate.py in _quaddist(self, value)
     91             onedim = False
     92
---> 93         delta = value - mu
     94
     95         if self._cov_type == 'cov':

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/var.py in __sub__(self, other)
    145         # and the return value in that case
    146         try:
--> 147             return theano.tensor.basic.sub(self, other)
    148         except (NotImplementedError, AsTensorError):
    149             return NotImplemented

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py in __call__(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    668                 # compute output value once with test inputs to validate graph
    669                 thunk = node.op.make_thunk(node, storage_map, compute_map,
--> 670                                            no_recycling=[])
    671                 thunk.inputs = [storage_map[v] for v in node.inputs]
    672                 thunk.outputs = [storage_map[v] for v in node.outputs]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py in make_thunk(self, node, storage_map, compute_map, no_recycling, impl)
    953             try:
    954                 return self.make_c_thunk(node, storage_map, compute_map,
--> 955                                          no_recycling)
    956             except (NotImplementedError, utils.MethodNotDefined):
    957                 # We requested the c code, so don't catch the error.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py in make_c_thunk(self, node, storage_map, compute_map, no_recycling)
    856         _logger.debug('Trying CLinker.make_thunk')
    857         outputs = cl.make_thunk(input_storage=node_input_storage,
--> 858                                 output_storage=node_output_storage)
    859         thunk, node_input_filters, node_output_filters = outputs
    860

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py in make_thunk(self, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map, keep_lock)
   1215         cthunk, module, in_storage, out_storage, error_storage = self.__compile__(
   1216             input_storage, output_storage, storage_map,
-> 1217             keep_lock=keep_lock)
   1218
   1219         res = _CThunk(cthunk, init_tasks, tasks, error_storage, module)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py in __compile__(self, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map, keep_lock)
   1155                                             output_storage,
   1156                                             storage_map,
-> 1157                                             keep_lock=keep_lock)
   1158         return (thunk,
   1159                 module,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py in cthunk_factory(self, error_storage, in_storage, out_storage, storage_map, keep_lock)
   1622                 node.op.prepare_node(node, storage_map, None, 'c')
   1623             module = get_module_cache().module_from_key(
-> 1624                 key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
   1625
   1626         vars = self.inputs + self.outputs + self.orphans

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py in module_from_key(self, key, lnk, keep_lock)
   1187             try:
   1188                 location = dlimport_workdir(self.dirname)
-> 1189                 module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
   1190                 name = module.__file__
   1191                 assert name.startswith(location)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py in compile_cmodule(self, location)
   1525                 lib_dirs=self.lib_dirs(),
   1526                 libs=libs,
-> 1527                 preargs=preargs)
   1528         except Exception as e:
   1529             e.args += (str(self.fgraph),)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py in compile_str(module_name, src_code, location, include_dirs, lib_dirs, libs, preargs, py_module, hide_symbols)
   2397             # difficult to read.
   2398             raise Exception('Compilation failed (return status=%s): %s' %
-> 2399                             (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
   2400         elif config.cmodule.compilation_warning and compile_stderr:
   2401             # Print errors just below the command line.

Exception: ("Compilation failed (return status=1): /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:544:27: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'npy_intp' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].     int init_totals[2] = {V1_n0, V3_n1};.                           ^~~~~. /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:544:27: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.     int init_totals[2] = {V1_n0, V3_n1};.                           ^~~~~.                           static_cast<int>( ). /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:544:34: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'npy_intp' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].     int init_totals[2] = {V1_n0, V3_n1};.                                  ^~~~~. /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:544:34: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.     int init_totals[2] = {V1_n0, V3_n1};.                                  ^~~~~.                                  static_cast<int>( ). /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:556:12: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing].         0, V3_stride1, .            ^~~~~~~~~~. /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:556:12: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue.         0, V3_stride1, .            ^~~~~~~~~~.            static_cast<int>( ). /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:557:4: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]. 0, V5_stride1, .    ^~~~~~~~~~. /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:557:4: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue. 0, V5_stride1, .    ^~~~~~~~~~.    static_cast<int>( ). /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:558:1: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]. V1_stride0, V1_stride1. ^~~~~~~~~~. /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:558:1: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue. V1_stride0, V1_stride1. ^~~~~~~~~~. static_cast<int>( ). /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:558:13: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]. V1_stride0, V1_stride1.             ^~~~~~~~~~. /Users/emdim/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.6-64/tmppq1_q56w/mod.cpp:558:13: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue. V1_stride0, V1_stride1.             ^~~~~~~~~~.             static_cast<int>( ). 6 errors generated.. ", '[Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, row)>, <TensorType(float64, row)>)]')
```

Can someone help me debug this? A colleague trie to run it on his machine and it worked, so I guess it has to do with my machine or maybe a version of theano or pymc3.

Or maybe it has to do with the shape argument, but once again I am skeptic since it has worked on my colleague's machine. 
I also tried to run the following command, but I am not sure what it does and I am afraid that it just hid warnings and important messages

```
theano.config.gcc.cxxflags = "-Wno-c++11-narrowing"
```

Finally, for Bayesian programmers (maybe it can help) the non-centred Cholesky reparametrization worked and compiled without error.
Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Hi Emile, [I hit this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51238578/570918) and ended up using the flag with no obvious consequences (running models on Linux for comparison gave similar results). Seems to have to do with a precision change involving multi-dim variables (`shape`) that clang defaults to raise as an error, and is not something that reparameterization would fix. In my mind, if the loss of precision were problematic it would make the sampler more prone to divergences. In that case, you'd see the divergences anyway and only then have to worry about reparameterizing.